# Searching R help for "for" and "repeat" loop(s) help file

Tags: r

I'm trying to load the page that describes these 'functions'. However, R console in windows seems to hate me, it just returns +

```
?for
?repeat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` is a reserved word.  You have to use backticks if you want to look it up:

```
?`for`
```

Comment: or single quotes or double quotes

Answer (score 2):

As a reference for others who may be interested in searching for help in R:

```
?read:delim                    #Access a functions help file
??base::delim                  #Search for "delim" in all help files for functions in base
help.search("delimited")       #Search for "delimited" in all help files
RSiteSearch("Parsing Text")    #Search for the term "Parsing Text" on the R site
```