# Getting help on R command line window

Tags: r

I wanted to get help about *repeat* in R command line window. But

```
> ?repeat  
+   
> help(repeat)  
Error: unexpected ')' in "help(repeat)"
```

*repeat* seems different from other functions. Also I found even for *if*, I also cannot get help document. So I assume help is just for non control-follow function/command? How to get the help document about control flow commands then?

Thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Searching R help for "for" and "repeat" loop(s) help file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376184/searching-r-help-for-for-and-repeat-loops-help-file) (first link if you search "[r] help" on SO)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`repeat`, `for`, etc are parts of the language that the parser gives high priority to; in this case R thinks you were going to write something it needed to evaluate *before* calling the function `?()` on the result. The canonical solution is to quote the function name using *backticks*:

```
?`repeat`
```

As DWin notes above, this can be used for any function name. Backticks are also useful for quoting objects or components of lists/data frames that have non-standard names.

Answer (score 6):

> help("repeat")
>
> ?"repeat"

Comment: And that is a general strategy, so that `?"if"` and even `?"<-"` or `?"["` will give meaningful responses

Comment: Double-quotes are optional.